# Filtering event ID 4771

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell I want to filter security event log for eventID 4771 for users only. Not for client computers.

The code I have on my end is giving me the results for both client computers and users failed login attempts. I am interested in seeing the failed login attempts by the user only.

```
$ns = @{e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"}

#$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Security" ;StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-1); ID = 4768,4771;keywords='8010000000000000'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = "Security" ;StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-2); ID = 4771;keywords='8010000000000000'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$results = foreach($evt in $events)
    {
    $xml = [xml]$evt.ToXml()

    $TUserName= Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='TargetUserName']/text()" |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
    $TargetUserName = $TUserName | Where-Object { $_ –notcontains "-AA-" -or $_ –notcontains "-BB-" -or $_ –notcontains "-CC-" -or $_ –notcontains "-DD-"}

    $Status = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='Status']/text()" |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    $IPAddress = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='IpAddress']/text()" |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    $IP = $IPAddress.Split(':')[-1]

    Switch ($Status)
        {
        "0x6"
            {
            $ReasonforLoginfailure = "Unknown user name"
            }
        "0x18"
            {
            $ReasonforLoginfailure = "Incorrect Password"
            }
        } 

    $IPPort = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='IpPort']/text()" |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{UserID = ($TargetUserName).Replace("$","")
                       HostName = $Hostname
                       IPAddress = $IP
                       Port = $IPPort
                       'TimeCreated in EST' = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($evt.TimeCreated, [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'Eastern Standard Time')
                       EventID = $evt.ID
                       Status = $Status
                       'Reason for Login failure' = $ReasonforLoginfailure
                       DomainName = $DC
                       }        
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For computer accounts, the `TargetUserName` field will end with `$`, so simply filter on that:

```
if($TargetUserName -like '*$'){
    # it's a computer
    # continue to the next event in the loop
    continue
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen. The code you provided me resolved the issue I am encountering on my end.